# Signing and Validating String using .cer (Public Key) and .pfx (Private Key) in Android (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, digital-signature, private-key, android-assets

I have a certificate which has 2 files generated

1. **abc.pfx**  (Kept in **asset** folder inside my Android project)
2. **xyx.cer**  (Kept in **raw** folder under **res** Folder)

I have been ask to digitally sign the data and post it via RestAPI through header as (AccessToken), which will than be validated at backend in C#

I am trying to digitally sign data using these files in my android App

**1) Below is the code which I am using to digitally sign the String**

```
public static byte[] getDigitallySigned (Context context, String Data){

        byte[] input = Data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] signed = null;
        try {
            InputStream cert= context.getAssets().open("abc.pfx");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(cert, "1234".toCharArray());

            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = null;
            PrivateKey pk = null;
            Enumeration<String> aliases;
            String alias = "";
            try {
                aliases = keyStore.aliases();
                while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                    alias = aliases.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(alias);
                    if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                        pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("1234".toCharArray()));
                        pk = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
                    }
                }
            } catch (KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("CATCH", e);
            }

            Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            instance.initSign(pk);
            instance.update(input);
             return  instance.sign();
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**2) Below is the code which I am using to Validate the signature**

```
public static boolean validateSignature(Context context,String data, String signature) {
        try {

            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xyx);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
            PublicKey publicKey = crt.getPublicKey();

            byte[] bytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(bytes);

            return sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature,Base64.NO_WRAP));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But when trying to validate the Signature it is giving false

```
String stringToEncrypt = "StackOverFlow";

byte[] result = EncryptionUtils.getDigitallySigned(mActivity,stringToEncrypt);
String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(result,Base64.NO_WRAP);


 if (validateSignature(mActivity,stringToEncrypt ,base64Encoded)){
      MessageLogger.msg("True");
 } else {
      MessageLogger.msg("False");
 }
```

Please let me know where I am going Wrong, I have tried everything I can, but no solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you certain xyz.cer contains the correct public key? The public key in xyx.cer should be equal to the public key obtained by `keyStore.getCertificate().getPublicKey()` in `getDigitallySigned`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, I checked public key of both files and they are identical.

Comment: Silly mistake done by me, While Signing I used **SHA256withRSA** and while validating I used **SHA512withRSA**. I have corrected to **SHA256** and its working now.